# Regex that accepts +, -, (, ), space, and numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

Please guide me to a regex that accepts any string with `+`, `-`, `(`, `)`, space, and numbers. For example, `89+98+67-45+(56+90)+()` is acceptable.

I have the following regex

```
validates :number, format: { with: /\A(?:[- +()0-9])\z/,
                              message: I18n.t('global.errors.phone_format')}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have forgotten a repeater:

```
/\A(?:[- +()0-9])\z/    # yours
/\A(?:[- +()0-9]+)\z/   # correct
```

Thanks to @Stefan, the group is superfluous:

```
/\A[- +()0-9]+\z/       # correct and clean
/\A[- +()\d]+\z/        # correct and possibly shortest :)
```

Comment: The non-capturing group is superfluous.

Comment: @Stefan, indeed. My intent was to make as few edits to original as possible. Anyway, updated.

Comment: I appreciate you taking that *shout-out* out of your answer :)

Comment: @mudasobwa a comment is usually sufficient in that case ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
\A(?:[- +()0-9])+\z
```

EDIT: As was pointed out, you don't need to escape inside `[...]`

Still captures correctly, however.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aY5fN2/4)

Comment: @user123 if this helped you don't forget to accept/upvote

Comment: @mudasobwa ahhh yea that's right. Still captured correctly, at least. I wouldn't call it necessarily wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

@sawa unfortunately deleted [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31857569/477037), but it was perfectly fine:

```
re = /[^+() \d-]/
"398hjfj"                !~ re # => false
"89+98+67-45+(56+90)+()" !~ re # => true
```

Since this is a *negative* match, it has to be used with the format validator's `:without` option:

```
validates :number, format: { without: /[^+() \d-]/ }
```